# Irreducibility of the adjoint representation in positive characteristic

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory

Let $G$ be a simple, simply connected, algebraic group over an algebraically closed field $k$ of characteristic $p>0$. Let $Ad$ be the adjoint representation of $G$ on $\mathrm{Lie}(G)$.

**Given the Dynkin diagram of $G$, for which $p$ is $Ad$ irreducible?**

I am happy to assume that $p$ is a very good prime for $G$.

Comment: I realised that the question has a simple answer: $Ad$ is irreducible whenever $\mathrm{Lie}(G)$ is a simple Lie algebra and this is indeed true for any very good prime. This follows, for example, from Steinberg's "Automorphisms of classical Lie algebras".